# Twilio - record incoming call recording callback

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twilio

Trying to use Twilio to receive an incoming call and ask the caller to leave a message.

For the most part, this is working fine.  However, the documentation eludes to being able to receive a webhook callback that will contain details of the recorded call - I want this so I can download the audio file and do what I need with it.

I've installed the `Twilio.AspNet.Mvc` nuget package (version 5.0.2), and my `a call comes in` webhook points to an MVC controller action that does this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var response = new VoiceResponse();

    response.Say("Thank you for calling.  Please leave a message.");

    response.Record(playBeep: true);

    response.Hangup();

    return new TwiMLResult(response);
}
```

So far, so good.  I call the number, and leave the message.

Now, in some of the documentation, the `Record` is supposed to take in a recording status callback URL, but there is no parameter available in `response.Record()`.

I've also set the `call status changes` webhook and captured the detail that is returned, but it only gives me details about the call (e.g. who from and duration) - there is no URL from where I can download the recording.

I know I can return a formatted TwiML document to do this (https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/record) via the `recordingStatusCallback` attribute, but is something missing from the nuget library, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

You say that you're using `Twilio.AspNet.Mvc` version 5.0.2, but that has a dependency on the [`Twilio` nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Twilio/). You'll need to make sure you're using the latest version of the Twilio package too, that is 5.5.0, which includes the `recordingStatusCallback` parameter for `response.Record()`.

Let me know if that helps at all.

Comment: That was it.   I had the checkbox for prerelease packages checked, and the current version is alpha, so I must have discounted that without looking too close.  Upgraded that package, and all good now.  Cheers for the fast answer.